# How can I get a random five elements from an array with handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I'm trying to use handlesbars with ghost and I want to get a random 10 tags from the tag list.

Is this possible?

Here's what I have now but I always get the same 10 tags.

```
                {{#get "tags" limit="10"}}
                    {{tags}}
                {{/get}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Randomising order is best done client-side than on the server, something like this would be a nice performant way to randomise the order of tags:

```
<span class="tags" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
  {{#get "tags" limit="all"}}
      {{tags separator=""}}
  {{/get}}
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const tags = document.querySelector('.tags');
  [...tags.children].forEach((tag, index) => {
    tag.style.order = Math.floor(Math.random() * tags.children.length)
  });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!